# After appending `numpy.ndarray` to a python list in a loop, data can not be correctly accessed

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I encountered a problem when using list in python.  I appended three `numpy.ndarray`s with different shapes to a list named `all_dets` in a loop. Then I printed out the elements in this list one by one to find that the elements were totally wrong! Here is the related code:

```
 for i in range(3):
        print 'detecting on image', image_paths[i] + ext
        im = cv2.imread(image_paths[i] + ext)
        print 'im.shape =', im.shape
        blobs_out = im_detect(net, im)
        print 'type(blobs_out) = ', type(blobs_out)
        print 'blobs_out.shape = ', blobs_out.shape
        all_dets.append(im_detect(net, im))
        # the following statement works correctly, but I don't know why
        # all_dets.append(np.array(im_detect(net, im), dtype=float))
        print all_dets[i], '\n'

    print '\n\n'
    for i in range(len(all_dets)):
        print all_dets[i], '\n'
```

Here is the output, where the data shows inconsistency. Why? Is it a bug?

```
detecting on image 2901.jpg
im.shape = (720, 1280, 3)
type(blobs_out) =  <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
blobs_out.shape =  (2, 6)
[[  3.00000000e+00   7.23988281e+02   1.99807007e+02   8.51956665e+02
    3.57274475e+02   9.98903632e-01]
 [  3.00000000e+00   9.50594910e+02   2.12917633e+02   1.09674084e+03
    3.62154694e+02   9.97807443e-01]] 

detecting on image 2902.jpg
im.shape = (720, 1280, 3)
type(blobs_out) =  <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
blobs_out.shape =  (1,)
[ 3.] 

detecting on image 2903.jpg
im.shape = (720, 1280, 3)
type(blobs_out) =  <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
blobs_out.shape =  (11, 6)
[[  1.00000000e+00   7.94668335e+02   2.84922882e+02   9.72878418e+02
    4.09533173e+02   9.99811232e-01]
 [  1.00000000e+00   6.11299622e+02   2.81592804e+02   6.46697083e+02
    3.24412018e+02   9.47641492e-01]
 [  3.00000000e+00   6.53184875e+02   2.65788025e+02   6.84356262e+02
    3.08493958e+02   9.21398461e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   6.95969604e+02   3.98138847e+01   7.36190674e+02
    7.37466125e+01   9.90691066e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   6.01833191e+02   0.00000000e+00   6.43418640e+02
    3.40718689e+01   9.90287900e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   8.83409363e+02   3.55691872e+01   9.16870911e+02
    6.30310249e+01   9.87128615e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   5.53889893e+02   7.42240906e-01   5.93223389e+02
    3.85933495e+01   9.80867684e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   5.55981384e+02   4.44181366e+01   5.94018616e+02
    8.16374359e+01   9.77178693e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   6.07572449e+02   4.32948265e+01   6.37179382e+02
    7.26311188e+01   9.76257086e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   8.35696045e+02   3.56059189e+01   8.70543091e+02
    7.16980743e+01   9.62459803e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   7.46284302e+02   3.84980392e+01   7.80992798e+02
    6.67527924e+01   9.32877839e-01]] 




[[  1.00000000e+00   7.94668335e+02   2.84922882e+02   9.72878418e+02
    4.09533173e+02   9.99811232e-01]
 [  1.00000000e+00   6.11299622e+02   2.81592804e+02   6.46697083e+02
    3.24412018e+02   9.47641492e-01]] 

[ 1.] 

[[  1.00000000e+00   7.94668335e+02   2.84922882e+02   9.72878418e+02
    4.09533173e+02   9.99811232e-01]
 [  1.00000000e+00   6.11299622e+02   2.81592804e+02   6.46697083e+02
    3.24412018e+02   9.47641492e-01]
 [  3.00000000e+00   6.53184875e+02   2.65788025e+02   6.84356262e+02
    3.08493958e+02   9.21398461e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   6.95969604e+02   3.98138847e+01   7.36190674e+02
    7.37466125e+01   9.90691066e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   6.01833191e+02   0.00000000e+00   6.43418640e+02
    3.40718689e+01   9.90287900e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   8.83409363e+02   3.55691872e+01   9.16870911e+02
    6.30310249e+01   9.87128615e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   5.53889893e+02   7.42240906e-01   5.93223389e+02
    3.85933495e+01   9.80867684e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   5.55981384e+02   4.44181366e+01   5.94018616e+02
    8.16374359e+01   9.77178693e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   6.07572449e+02   4.32948265e+01   6.37179382e+02
    7.26311188e+01   9.76257086e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   8.35696045e+02   3.56059189e+01   8.70543091e+02
    7.16980743e+01   9.62459803e-01]
 [  7.00000000e+00   7.46284302e+02   3.84980392e+01   7.80992798e+02
    6.67527924e+01   9.32877839e-01]]
```

Comment: Sounds like you're taking views where you think you're making copies; these arrays all seem to be views into the same array.

Comment: @user2357112 I noticed that. It is a very strange behavior and doesn't make sense.